# Stored procedure syntax structure

Tags: sql-server

I get error why?

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.verifGuids

@value char(36),
@message char(1)Output
AS

 Begin

 select value FROM guids WHERE @value=value; 

  If @value=value 
  BEGIN
  DELETE value FROM guids WHERE @value=value ;
  SET @message = 0
  END

  Else 
  BEGIN
  Set @message = 1
  END

  Return @message

  END
```

Thanks

Comment: What actual error do you get?

Comment: column value no valid this in VS...

Comment: this line is pointless and doesn't assign anything: select value FROM guids WHERE @value=value

Comment: You need to fix up the `If @value=value` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try as below way:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.verifGuids
@value char(36),
@message char(1)Output
AS
Begin

DECLARE @SelectValue char(36)

select @SelectValue = value FROM guids WHERE @value=value; 

If @value=@SelectValue 
BEGIN
    DELETE value FROM guids WHERE @value=value ;
    SET @message = 0
END
Else 
BEGIN
    Set @message = 1
END

Return @message
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the database value you are querying into a variable for comparison. Also you are specifying the column when deleting. Try something like this:

```
DELETE FROM guids WHERE value=@value;
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    SET @message = 0
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SET @message = 1
END
```